# Kivy demo video player does not work in Win-7-32 Python 3.4.4 Kivy 1.9.1, no error msg

Tags: python, video, kivy

> I have been spending the day trying to get the demo video player to work. I have tried different types of videos and the default Softboy. It looks fine loading, shows the matching picture, and no error messages. Clicking on the start arrow it tuns into a spinner and it spins forever.  It has not crashed , I can click on audio on of (but no sound) and start-stop.  It works normally,  just no video playing and no audio.  The videos play fine on my PC.
>   I have spent decades writing embedded assembly code but Python & Kivy are new to me and the learning curve is painful.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.2.0')

from sys import argv
from os.path import dirname, join
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer

class VideoPlayerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        if len(argv) > 1:
            filename = argv[1]
        else:
            curdir = dirname(__file__)
#            filename = ('Vid_Demon.avi')
#            filename = ('Vid_Wire.mp4')
#            filename = ('Vid_Archer.mov')
#            filename = ('Vid_Bowl.mp4')
#            filename = ('Softboy.mpg')
            filename = ('Softboy.avi')

        return VideoPlayer(source=filename, state='play')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoPlayerApp().run()
```